# http/https no image displaying problem with site collection usage summary page

Tags: sharepoint

The problem is that when I go to site collection usage summary page under a site collection no statistical images are displayed and only in https. http works fine and let me explain why.

External users hit the proxy switching the protocol to https in turn causing a failure for many features because SharePoint return some JavaScript URLS in http. So in AAM I configured SharePoint to us HTTPS as follows:

```
http://example.com:81
Default
http://example.com:81

http://example.com
Internet
https://www.example.com

https://www.example.com
Internet
https://www.example.com

http://www.example.com
Internet
https://www.example.com
```

In addition, I added a host header in IIS 6. The result is as expected minus the only problem with `Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd` on the site usage page is not displaying the images (data is fine). After inspecting the broken image it is requesting http and not https. No error is displayed.

Has anybody experienced this problem or have a suggestion to fix this report service?

MOSS 2007, Windows Server 2003, IIS 6

Answer (score 1):

When SharePoint gets the request you need to make sure that the request it thinks it is getting is the actual URL it is publishing. So for example if your proxy server is accepting the request as https://foobar.com/ then it will need to send that same URL to SharePoint . This is the only way that AAM will know how to serve back the correct URL as SharePoint sends back the same URL that was requested as long as that URL is configured in AAM.

Answer (score 0):

Are you hard-coding the URLs in the page?  A trick often used is to drop the protocol from image URL.  `<img src="//host/image/path/img.png">`

Found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565655(VS.85).aspx) in the *Workaround for Web Developers* section.

> For example, if you have an image on www.fabrikam.com/account.htm that is addressable using either http:// or https://, you must use [image] instead of .

Comment: I failed to point out that this is a problem with existing SharePoint technology. SharePoint dynamically creates the links on page load, so no I am not hard coding the URLs. FYI ~\whatever.jpg works too.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change your "Alternate access links" internal link to "Internal" and the external link to "default".
Or some combination thereof.